# Why weren't the Weasleys a part of the Original Order?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did Arthur and Molly Weasley not join the original iteration of the Order of the Phoenix, during the First Wizarding War? We know that they were definitely old enough to join (it is stated in the Goblet of Fire that the Whomping Willow was planted after Molly left Hogwarts, and we know that it was planted in Lupin's first year).

**So why did Arthur and Molly not take part in the original order, and its resistance against Voldemort?**

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is no direct canon information (books, interviews, pottermore that I checked).

However, by the time Harry's parents were murdered, Weasleys already had 6.5 kids (F&G were 2 years ahead of Harry, Ron was same age, Ginny 1 year younger). Wikia gives the date range as

> Bill was born in 1970, which is approximately when the war began, and Ginny was born in 1981, two months before the end of the war

Having 5-6-7 small kids to raise kind of puts a damper on most people's most activities, be it social life, or participation in secret orders.

Comment: Ugh, if I had a nickel for every secret order I couldn't join because of the kids...

Comment: @Nerrolken - I'll settle for a nickel for every time I didn't get to engage in intimate adult recreational activity because of the kids...

Comment: @DVK you'd either have a lot of nickels or a lot of kids.

Comment: Make that a galleon.

Comment: Ron was about Harry's age during the fist wizarding war. Having to look after an infant while taking part in a war would have been very difficult for Molly.

Comment: @DVK, this is what I suspected, was just hoping that there might be canon evidence. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Building on @DVKs answer, JKR has confirmed [on her own website](http://web.archive.org/web/20070724183339/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=27) that Gideon and Fabian Prewitt (both of whom were members of the original Order of the Phoenix) were in fact [Molly's older brothers](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gideon_Prewett):

> "No one lived after he decided ter kill 'em, no one except you, an'
>   he'd killed some of the best witches and wizards of the age — the
>   McKinnons, the Bones, **the Prewetts**.

Although there's no canon confirmation one way or another, it's a distinct possibility that they were instrumental in Molly *not* becoming a member of such a dangerous organisation, basically vetoing their baby sister from joining.

We see a similar occurrence in the books, with Molly seeming to bar Ron, Harry and Hermione from becoming full members.

Comment: Ughm... Did you read the same Harry Potter that I did? :) When did anyone manage to succeed in getting Molly to do anything other than what she WANTED to do?

Comment: @DVK - Arguably, the death of her older brothers could have been the spur into action that she needed to get more involved.

Comment: A "baby" sister... with 6.5 kids?

Comment: @algiogia - I can assure you that that's irrelevant :-)

Comment: My brother, who is seven years younger than me and the youngest of my siblings, is now over a foot taller than me. I still call him "shorty" and "small-fry." Nicknames stick, especially for the "baby" of the family, even long after they are relevant.